# Connect Laravel/ CI to Docker

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, codeigniter

[This is my docker-compose.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H497j.png)

[my Env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0tKU.png)

[This is my adminer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZu1d.png)

Please help me im still new on these things , how to connect the db to the one that docker adminer provide?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, can you review this question and answers, to why not post code as image. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

Change DB_HOST in Your .env file from localhost ip to name of mysql container (db).